# My UpdatePanel containing a DropDowList isn't updating after I select an object from my ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

It seems like my update panel isn't updating my form after I click an item in my listview.  When I pass by breakpoint in my load method it seems to input everything properly and yet...

.aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlConfig" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the object
    //...
    //Assign the value to the DropDownList
    this.ddlConfig.Items.FindByText(Configurations.Find(d => d.ID == ConfigurationID).Name).Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used something similar in my project and perhaps there's several objects getting selected in the dropdownlist at the same time ? If so, try something like this

```
//Assign the value found to the selectedValue of the ddlConfig
this.ddlConfig.SelectedValue =  this.ddlConfig.Items.FindByText(Configurations.Find(d => d.ID == ConfigurationID).Name).Value;
```

Comment: Thanks copy pasted and it worked great, it's probably because the way I was using it bypassed the framework method for selecting an item in a DropdownList.